# Aws lightsail instance details

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to get an all the  details of all the instances available on the aws using python.I am able to get the e2c instances details but not able to get the lightsail details using python? I have the cli command to get the deatils but I want to get all lightsail instance details using python.

Code which I am using to get ec2 instance is below:

```
import boto3
region = 'ap-south-1'



ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region)

result = []  

for instance in ec2.instances.all():
    print(
        "Id: {0}\nPlatform: {1}\nType: {2}\nPublic IPv4: {3}\nAMI: {4}\nState: {5}\nTags: {6}\n".format(
            instance.id, instance.platform, instance.instance_type, instance.public_ip_address, instance.image.id, instance.state, instance.tags
            )
       )
```

And the cli command to get lightsail details is

```
aws lightsail get-instances --region ap-south-1 --query 'instances[].{blueprintId:blueprintId,publicIpAddress:publicIpAddress,Tags:Tags,name:name}' --output table
```

Can please anyone help me with python script to get the lightsail details?

Answer (score 0):

So far you have called the EC2 API to get a list of EC2 instances. The EC2 API is only going to give you a list of EC2 instances. That API is not going to give you any of your Lightsail instances.

You already have the AWS CLI tool command to get the information you want: `aws lightsail get-instances`. Note how you are not using an `aws ec2` command. You are using a `aws lightsail` command. Similarly in Boto3 you would not use the EC2 client to query for Lightsail servers, you would use the [Lightsail](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lightsail.html) client. Boto3 has a Lightsail [get_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lightsail/client/get_instances.html) function that directly corresponds to the CLI command you are using.